# Concat two data frame row wise which have different column names and different values in row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe which have few column comman and few columns are different. And each dataframe have 1 Row only and contains the information about different runs. so how can I combined then to create 1 dataframe with 2 rows.

ex:

```
df:
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3

df:
   a  y  c
0  4  5  6
```

This is just example for two dataframe, but I will be doing it for multiple dataframes with each 1 row.

Comment: Have you tried `pd.concat([df1, df2])` ?

Comment: yeah that didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want to combine dfs and want to keep values together in some list of sort, for that you can do:

```
pd.concat([df,df2]).reset_index().groupby('index').agg(list).reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
        a           b       c           y
0  [1, 4]  [2.0, nan]  [3, 6]  [nan, 5.0]
```

OR, if you just want to combine them then, `pd.concat` does it

```
pd.concat([df,df2]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
   a    b  c    y
0  1  2.0  3  NaN
1  4  NaN  6  5.0
```